# Update value in another form's textbox via VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, reference, controls

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm frustrated that I cannot figure this out. I have a simple Access 2010 database. I have a simple form inside it that helps the user input some specific information. This data entry situation can occur on two other forms in the database. Rather than have two copies of the "helper" form where the VBA code has hard-coded control references, I wanted to make it more universal by passing the name of the form that calls it by using the openArgs parameter.

When the time comes to transfer the values BACK to the form that needs the information, the helper form attempts to do this like so:

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    Dim theFormName As String
    Dim theForm As Form

    theFormName = Me.OpenArgs
    Set theForm = Forms.Item(theFormName)

    If Not IsNull(theForm.Name) Then
        theForm.txtLongitude.Value = Me.lblLongitude.Caption
        theForm.txtLatitude.Value = Me.lblLatitude.Caption
    End If

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
End Sub
```

The variable `theForm` is populated correctly and `theForm.Name` returns the correct name of the form so that part works fine. The problem is that `theForm.<controlName>.Value` does not. When I run the code, I get an

> application-defined or object-defined error (Run-time Error 2465)

I've tried all sorts of permutations for the control reference from the current open form to a second open form but I cannot get the syntax right. I've tried:

```
theForm!txtLongitude.Value ("..can't find the field txtLongitude..")
theForm.Controls("txtLongitude").Value ("..cant find the field...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions.  If one works, let me know and I'll edit my answer to only include the one that works.

1. Try changing `theForm.txtLongitude.Value = Me.lblLongitude.Caption`
   to `Forms!theForm!txtLongitude.Value = Me!lblLongitutde.Caption` and `theForm.txtLatitude.Value = Me.lblLatitude.Caption` to `Forms!theForm!txtLatitude.Value = Me!lblLatitude.Caption`
2. If you've already tried that or it doesn't work, try declaring variables and "pulling" the values out of one form before putting them in the other form. (Also make sure the data type of both are the same.)

   Private Sub Command4_Click()
           Dim theFormName As String
           Dim theForm As Form

   ```
       Dim txtLong As String
       Dim txtLat As String

       txtLong = Me.lblLongitude.Caption
       txtLat = Me.lblLatitude.Caption

       theFormName = Me.OpenArgs
       Set theForm = Forms.Item(theFormName)

       If Not IsNull(theForm.Name) Then
           theForm.txtLongitude.Value = txtLong
           theForm.txtLatitude.Value = txtLat
       End If

       DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo

       End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I marked your answer correct as your second option listed works. As it turns out, so does my original code. In classic n00b fashion, I thought I had renamed my textbox controls in my other form to the names referenced in my code but, alas, I had not. Once I made that change, the original code worked. DOH!